# How can I the box blur algorithm with an array of structs to blur an image?

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, struct, cs50

The question might be confusing at first but i have formulated a function that performs a blur filter onto a set input picture (the function is quite long). If im completely honest, i dont know where i messed up but the code doesn't work.

Here is the function:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE average[height][width];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++ )
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++ )
        {
            if ( (i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == width - 1) )
            {
                if ( j == 0 )
                {
                    average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                }
                else if( j == width - 1)
                {
                    average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                }
            }
            else if ( i == 0 )
            {
                average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
            }
            else if ( (i == height - 1 && j == 0) || (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1) )
            {
                if ( j == 0 )
                {
                    average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                }
                else if( j == width - 1)
                {
                    average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                    average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                }
            }
            else if ( i == height - 1)
            {
                average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
            }
            else if ( j == 0 )
            {
                average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
            }
            else if ( j == width - 1 )
            {
                average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
            }
            else 
            {
                average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed)/9.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue)/9.0);
                average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(((float)image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen)/9.0);
            }
        }
    }
    memcpy(image, average, sizeof(image));
}
```

Here is the struct that defines the RGBTRIPLE class:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

These are the points i need to develop:

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "120 140 150\n"
:) blur correctly filters pixel on edge
:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."

Link to checker is: https://submit.cs50.io/check50/4c25523bd0c350f307c8b7e47326b0f3e40c5b31
```

Any input would help! Thank you so much in advance

Comment: `image = average;` I'm sorry, but you need to copy the content manually.

Comment: Are you trying to perform an _in-place_ blur?  (where the input array gets modified and its original contents are overwritten with the blurred version?)

Comment: @Wyck It is an in-place blur, the original image needs to be modified.

Comment: @Gerhardh I tried that but it only ticks off two of the points

Comment: Tick off ... which points? You know that you did not include any description what is going wrong. No expected output, not output you got, no input, ... All of those are important

Comment: @Gerhardh CS50 doesnt give you the full output but i have included all the points i need to tick off

Comment: @Gerhardh The checker is on the actual post

Comment: You can clearly see that your problem is located at middle pixels. Check your final else and you will notice wrong index values: `average[i][j].rgbtRed=... + (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed +   (float)image[i+1][j].rgbtRed +   (float)image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed` you use `j-1`twice and miss `j+1`. This is true for all 3 colors

Comment: You should use size of your `average` array because array parameters (`image`) decay to pointers when passed to functions: `memcpy(image, average, sizeof(image));` You will not copy enough values.

Comment: @Gerhardh I updated the post and i still get the same results with those changes

Comment: Oh, and please do not change your code after comments and answers have been provided. That makes them useless for further readers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220147/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-george-khanachat).